# In framework 7(phonegap) You can swipe from the left edge of the screen to go back, is it possible to disable this gesture?

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

In framework 7(phonegap) added a new default navigation behavior. You can swipe from the left edge of the screen to go back on the navigation stack. But in my app, this behavior conflicts with my custom left menu. So, is it possible to disable this new gesture?

Answer (score 1):

In your initialize call add

```
swipeBackPage: false
```

And you're all set

Src: http://framework7.io/docs/init-app.html